# Which of two installed Graphics cards is being used by a program?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I use Windows 10 Pro in my PC and I would like to know which of the two installed graphics cards VLC Player is using, or even other programs.

Can please someone tell me which is the best way to do this?
 
Some additional information: 
I use a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti and an onboard Intel UHD 630. 
Meanwhile I found out (thanks to harrymc) that VLC Player uses the onboard card but 
I want to also try out the NVIDIA card 
(hopping to eliminate the delay at the restarting of a loop).

Comment: Which graphics card is the monitor plugged in to?

Comment: I think the onboard one, Intel UHD 630, since the monitors went off and on when I updated the video card drivers.

Answer (score 1):

To observe the general usage if the two GPUs, start Task Manager, go to the
*Performance* tab. You may note here which GPU is your GPU0 and which is GPU1:

[image]

Still in the Task Manager, go to the *Processes* tab and
click on GPU Engine tab to sort the programs by GPU usage, to see which
application is using which GPU:

[image]

If you want to change the GPU being used by an app and you have an NVIDIA card,
this can be done using the NVIDIA Control panel.

Comment: Great! So I can see at least which card is being used. Nevertheless I couldn't find the location in NVIDIA Control Panel (8.1.10.40.0) where I can set the App to use this video card. Even if I found the most possible location under Manage 3D settings/Program settings/VLC player, I wasn't able to find the applicable setting...

Comment: You are right, the affinity setting has disappeared from the NVIDIA Control panel. Apparently it's no longer supported. You can still in Task Manager right-click a running process and choose "Set affinity". Unfortunately this will only last until the process stops.

Comment: Que pena! What a pity! And "Set affinity" doesn't exist in the process's context. Is it a very new option or an obsolete one? By the way the NVIDIA card isn't being used at all (except of the Monitor)...

Comment: For "Set affinity" you need to be in the Details tab.

Comment: That's right, thanks! But it seems that you can choose only the CPU here. No GPU is listed...

Comment: No way to do that any more.